# Can Ethernet cable be used to extend USB cable?

Tags: usb, ethernet

here is my situation.  I have my cable modem and router in my upstairs bedroom.  The router also has USB 3.0 ports for connecting USB storage.  I would like to hook up USB hard drives to the router, but they are too noisy for my liking to stay in the bedroom near the router.  My house is pre-wired with Ethernet cable which goes to other rooms, with the hub near the router.  My question is, is there such a cable which adapts USB to Ethernet, such that in effect I can use the Ethernet cable pre-wired in my house to extend a USB connection to other rooms, where I can house my hard drives?

Comment: There really is no such thing as ethernet cable. I think you mean your house is wired with UTP category cable. This can be used for telephone, audio, token ring, ethernet, etc.

Comment: I recommend against that, moving the router is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  You can create your own cables, or buy [premade](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000O2X2OA) ones.  I dont believe you can get the 198 feet they advertise, but I have seen self made extenders that run 25 feet.

Comment: I see the ones in your link are USB 1.x, which won't work too well for a hard drive due to the low bandwidth.  But it's good to know they make these things.  I'll probably move the router instead as John suggested.